# Chipset GPU causes a massive slowdown

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, performance, gpu

My AMD Radeon HD 7700 recently broke (fan stopped working and GPU overheated), and now I'm running on internal chipset graphics, and ***it causes a massive slowdown of the whole PC.***

I've changed the graphics memory from 32MB (minimum) to 256MB (highest), and it hasn't made any difference whatsoever.
I'm using Windows Aero, and disabling it should have made a small difference, but it didn't; the whole PC is still slow.

I know that it's not the computer build, because I built it myself, and it was *a lot faster* when it had the AMD Radeon HD 7700 in it, which is the reason why I believe it's the internal chipset graphics that are causing the problem.

Is this behavior normal?
I don't have the cash right now to go out and buy a new dedicated GPU.

I'm using an [ASRock N68C-GS FX](http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-GS%20FX/) motherboard with an AMD FX 4100 (overclocked to 4.3GHZ), with 4GB RAM.
The overclock was an attempt to resolve this issue, and it isn't related to this issue that the integrated graphics is causing a slowdown.

I'm also running on a completely clean install of Windows 7.

Device Manager, as someone requested it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you completely removed the AMD driver and cleaned your registry with CCleaner?

Even if your integrated GPU is AMD, I would uninstall and re-install the drivers for good measure.

It is possible that your integrated graphics are not being utilized at all so having the CPU process your interactions with the GUI would explain this slowdown.

It is also possible that you have not installed all of the chipset drivers so Windows doesn't know how to interact with the integrated graphics.

Check your device manager and make sure it lists your integrated GPU:

[image]

I am also assuming that you have removed your dead GPU right?

**Update**

From your screenshot I see you are using the drivers provided by Microsoft Update. You should try uninstalling the driver by right-clicking on that item in the device manager and choosing Uninstall Driver. When Windows tries to install it again, do not allow it to do so.

Get the latest driver from nVidia and install it. Make sure you are cleaning the registry and rebooting your PC after each install/un-install.

Comment: Yes, I'm also running on a clean install of Windows 7, so it can't be the OS.

Comment: Yes what? Please be more specific when there are clearly multiple questions being asked of you. Please see the update.

Comment: Obviously I've removed my dead GPU, I'm going to try installing the official Nvidia driver.

Comment: Turned out to be either a faulty device, or my BIOS. I removed a wireless networking card, and updated my BIOS to the latest beta version, and it works. Not sure why, because the BIOS is an older version than the previous one (previous was 1.40, now using L1.01).